# Can I customize Buddypress to make each member able to upload podcasts?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to make a podcasts platform.

Buddypress already comes with amazing features, I think it is better to build upon it.

Can I customize it to add ability for every user to upload podcasts for himself?

If yes,
What I need to learn to make this addition?